# ASP MVC - Front End & Back End

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

After seeing some cool videos of how easy it to make `ASP.NET MVC 4.0/4.5 Azure` project with code first which gives u CRUD so easy,

My question is : **How I split the page for Admin / End User ?** ( Assume you using the mvc 4.0 application template )

*For example :* If I make ItemController with Item model in my web www.example.com/Item, I want www.example.com/Item to show my items for end users in my design, but all the crud operation for Item in Admin/Item or something like that ( with Rules and etc ),

Are there any examples I can out there?

Comment: This doesn't really sound like and MVC issue, more about how to implement row level security.

Comment: Its both I think , security +  project structure ,my question was needed to be more accurate :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx) in ASP.NET MVC. Areas allow you to split your site in multiple units (like your public website and the admin portal):

[image]

Areas also make it easier to handle routes, where you can map **/admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}** to the Admin area for example.

Comment: Assume you using the asp.net mvc 4 application template which already have a though of structure design , what's your suggestion also? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On your page mark-up you can use something like that to insert admin only functionality:

```
@if (Context.User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")
}
```

It is assumed that roles are set up.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the best option is to put the frontend and the backend in separate projects in the same solution. You can have problems with frontend users attempting to access the windows administrator